# call_user_func_array() - Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to bind parameters dynamically using an array. This is the part of my code which is important and also shows debugging info:

```
$params = array_merge( array( $one ), array_values( $two ) );
echo '<pre>';
echo $query . '<br><br>';
print_r( $params );
call_user_func_array( array( &$stmt, 'bind_param' ), MakeValuesReferenced( $params ) );
```

This is the debugging info:

[image]

As you can see there are three question marks in my query, and three parameters added to bind_param. I thought this should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quote the placeholder, that makes it the literal value and not a placeholder. Move the time into the binding and leave the placeholders on their own.

e.g.

```
where thedateandtime between ? and ?
```

then in the bind

```
($date . ' 00:00:00')
```

You also can't bind columns so the `order` by should be altered. Use a whitelist to compare the values before passing it into the query.